# Enhance performance on multiple promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, promise

So, I've got a bunch of promises that I need to store in different variables that will then be the values for different objects keys, that object will be returned to the API and served to the user.

The problem that I am facing is that it is slow (between 150ms to 1000ms).

Is there a better way to get all these promises served faster? or just avoid them? Can't use Promise.all() as all the values have to be stored in different variables.

```
  const scheduledTotalExVat = await calculateFieldTotal(scheduledMilestones, 'totalPriceExVat');
  const scheduledTotalIncVat = await calculateFieldTotal(scheduledMilestones, 'totalPriceIncVat');
  const achievedTotalExVat = await calculateFieldTotal(achievedMilestones, 'totalPriceExVat');
  const achievedTotalIncVat = await calculateFieldTotal(achievedMilestones, 'totalPriceIncVat');
  const invoicedTotalExVat = await calculateFieldTotal(invoicedMilestones, 'totalPriceExVat');
  const invoicedTotalIncVat = await calculateFieldTotal(invoicedMilestones, 'totalPriceIncVat');
  const paidTotal = await calculateFieldTotal(paidMilestones, 'amountPaid');
  const totalExVat = await calculateFieldTotal(allMilestones, 'totalPriceExVat');
  const totalIncVat = await calculateFieldTotal(allMilestones, 'totalPriceIncVat');
  const quotationTotalExVat = await calculateFieldTotal(projectQuotations, 'totalPriceExVat');
  const quotationTotalIncVat = await calculateFieldTotal(projectQuotations, 'totalPriceIncVat');

  const summary = {
    milestonesScheduledExVat: scheduledTotalExVat,
    milestonesScheduledIncVat: scheduledTotalIncVat,
    milestonesAchievedExVat: achievedTotalExVat,
    milestonesAchievedIncVat: achievedTotalIncVat,
    milestonesInvoicedExVat: invoicedTotalExVat,
    milestonesInvoicedIncVat: invoicedTotalIncVat,
    milestonesPaid: paidTotal,
    milestonesTotalExVat: totalExVat,
    milestonesTotalIncVat: totalIncVat,
    unbilledTotalExVat: quotationTotalExVat - paidTotal,
    unbilledTotalIncVat: quotationTotalIncVat - paidTotal,
  };

  return summary;
```

That calculateFieldTotal() function is nothing more than a short code to loop through an array of objects and add up the value for an specific field.

```
  async function calculateFieldTotal(arrayOfObjects, fieldToCalculate) {
  if (!arrayOfObjects || !fieldToCalculate) {
    throw new Error('Missing fields for calculation.');
  }

  return (
    arrayOfObjects
      .map(obj => parseFloat(obj[fieldToCalculate]))
      .reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0) || 0
  );
}
```

I don't really like how this looks but I can't find a more scalable or pretty way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the nature of `.map` and `.reduce` are synchronous, why are you using `async` and `await` for them?

Comment: If I don't, the values are not valid. But even with that is still slow.

Comment: in which way the values are not valid? can you show us an example, maybe a [mcve]?
Also, when resolved, a `promise.all()` returns an array where each value is the result of each promise/function called...

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the values removing async from the function and the await from the values, but it is still slow, around 125ms.

Comment: `Can't use Promise.all(), values have to be stored in different variables.`  That's not a limitation of `Promise.all`

Comment: `calculateFieldTotal, loop through an array of objects and add up the value`  Are you saying this is not async, if so, your await's are doing nothing..

Comment: A series of awaits means a series of asynchronous processes in series; each of them awaits the previous one to settle, before commencing. If possible, perform the `calculateFieldTotal()` operations in parallel.

Comment: `calculateFieldTotal()` isn't asynchronous. There's no need for it to be `async` nor to `await` the returned value.

Comment: How big is this array?..  Because even doing thousands using the code  you have provided, should be happening in milliseconds.  And your `calculateFieldTotal` is indeed not `async`, so marking async & using await will actually slow things down.  And depending on what promise lib your using, this could be large.  From what I remember some promise libs used to enforce a next tick.

Comment: There is very simple sequelize query to gather all the data prior to those calculations and a bunch of reduce calls to get specific values from that query so I can calculate the correct things.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Promise.all` and store the results in different variables:

```
const [
  scheduledTotalExVat,
  scheduledTotalIncVat,
  achievedTotalExVat,
  achievedTotalIncVat,
  invoicedTotalExVat,
  invoicedTotalIncVat,
  paidTotal,
  totalExVat,
  totalIncVat,
  quotationTotalExVat,
  quotationTotalIncVat
] = await Promise.all([
  calculateFieldTotal(scheduledMilestones, "totalPriceExVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(scheduledMilestones, "totalPriceIncVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(achievedMilestones, "totalPriceExVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(achievedMilestones, "totalPriceIncVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(invoicedMilestones, "totalPriceExVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(invoicedMilestones, "totalPriceIncVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(paidMilestones, "amountPaid"),
  calculateFieldTotal(allMilestones, "totalPriceExVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(allMilestones, "totalPriceIncVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(projectQuotations, "totalPriceExVat"),
  calculateFieldTotal(projectQuotations, "totalPriceIncVat")
]);

const summary = {
  milestonesScheduledExVat: scheduledTotalExVat,
  milestonesScheduledIncVat: scheduledTotalIncVat,
  milestonesAchievedExVat: achievedTotalExVat,
  milestonesAchievedIncVat: achievedTotalIncVat,
  milestonesInvoicedExVat: invoicedTotalExVat,
  milestonesInvoicedIncVat: invoicedTotalIncVat,
  milestonesPaid: paidTotal,
  milestonesTotalExVat: totalExVat,
  milestonesTotalIncVat: totalIncVat,
  unbilledTotalExVat: quotationTotalExVat - paidTotal,
  unbilledTotalIncVat: quotationTotalIncVat - paidTotal
};

return summary;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however, responding to initial comments, that doesn't solve the performance issue.

Comment: @Scarecrowsama  Then the performance issue is not the code you have shown.  `calculateFieldTotal` is the bottleneck.

Comment: There is a very simple sequelize query before that, but it shouldn't take that long, is quite simple.

Comment: @Scarecrowsama  Have a gut feeling its maybe taking longer than you think :), because a query is simple doesn't always mean it's fast, none fitting indexes etc on what appears to be simple is often the root cause of performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Scarecrowsama try measuring the time those queries take, ( check if you're opening / closing DB connection with every query )